# "В этом смысле" — вводное выражение?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Подскажите, является ли в следующем предложении выражение "в этом смысле" вводным?

> В этом смысле(,) мы можем поучиться у этих товарищей".

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это наречное выражение. Запятой не отделяется:

http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=289